# $\alpha$-arithmetic

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic

Has anyone heard of an $\alpha$-arithmetic before? The idea appears in Grossman & Katz book on Non-Newtonian Calculus (1972), but I'm wondering if this definition is out-dated and has perhaps been replaced by a modern equivalent?

According to the reference, an $\alpha$-arithmetic is defined as a set $A$ with operations $\oplus,\ominus,\otimes,\div,<$, and a bijective function $\alpha$, such that:

$$x\oplus y = \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x)+\alpha^{-1}(y))$$
$$x\ominus y = \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x)-\alpha^{-1}(y))$$
$$x\otimes y = \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x)\times\alpha^{-1}(y))$$
$$x\div y= \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x) / \alpha^{-1}(y))$$
$$x < y \iff \alpha^{-1}(x) < \alpha^{-1}(y).$$

When $\alpha$ is the identity function, we obtain the *classical arithmetic*.

N.B. I'm not sure about some Latex symbols that's why I've not used circles around the divide and inequality signs in the left hand expressions or inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to implicitly assume there is a structure of field on $A$ since you use the addition, multiplication, and division (or some kind of commutative ring, if you have suitable restrictions on the division). So what you have is just a field and a permutation of this field. The new law are just what you get from the old law by "transfer of structure" by the permutation. (Actually a bijection to another set is a more natural setting.) It is indeed out-dated since algebraic structures and isomorphisms are standard in the mathematical intuition.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they will be useful. Out of interest, do you happen to know roughly (what decade or year) when the concept of *isomorphism* was realized?

Comment: I think the authors are alluding to isomorphisms of the complete ordered field $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @pbs: Isomorphisms of fields have been studied since 1800s. I'm not sure who first formalized it. *Transfer of structure* has been around as well.